# Conformal map from two disks to the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a conformal equivalence f from $U$ onto $ D = \{ z : |z| < 1 \} $, where $U=\{z: |z+1|<2\}\cup \{z: |z-1|<2\}.$

How to find such a map $f$? I think we need to map the two discs to two strips individually. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: $D$ is connected and $U$ is not – they cannot be conformally equivalent.

Comment: @MartinR It's a typo. The radius should be 2.

Answer (score 4):

Let $P,Q$ be the two points of intersection of the two circles.

First apply a Möbius transformation that takes $P$ to $0$ and takes $Q$ to $\infty$. The image of your region is now an angle bounded by two rays.

Next, apply a power transformation $z \mapsto z^s$ where the exponent $s$ is chosen so that the union of the two rays is mapped to a straight line through $0$. The image of the region is now a half plane bounded by that line.

Now apply a Mobius transformation which takes the half plane to the disc $D$.